# How to get user's avatar when it's in in_group_of posts loop ? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails.

I've **posts** and **users**. Users `has_many` posts, and post `belongs_to` user.

When I run the following code, I get 3 times the same user's avatar.

However, each user had its own avatar. **How can I get the right user's avatar for each user into my div card ?**

```
 <% @Posts.limit(3).in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% group.each do |post| %>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <% @user.limit(1).each do |user| %>
        <div class="card">
          <img src="<%= user.image.url(:thumb) %>" alt="<%= user.name %>" class="avatar-small card-user">
          <% end %> 
          <div class="card-description">
            <a href="<%= posts_path(post.slug) %>"><h3><%= post.title %></h3></a>
            <p><%= post.subtitle %></p>
          </div>
        </div></a>
      </div>
     <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my controller :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @Posts = Post.all   
    @user = User.all  
  end
end
```

schema.rb :

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.string   "subtitle"
  end
```

I use Paperclip and administrate gem.

Thank a lot for your help.
Tell me if you need more infos.

Comment: why dont you try to eager load to avoid this problem..try something like :@post = Post.includes(:users).limit(3) and then every post have their own users ...

Answer (score 0):

So to get the correct user for each post you can just do post.user.img_url. So in your example the following should work. Notice how there is no need to iterate through the @users, you can just find the user that belongs to the post by using the association post.user .

```
<% @Posts.limit(3).in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
<div class="row">
  <% group.each do |post| %>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="<%= post.user.image.url(:thumb) %>" alt="<%= user.name %>" class="avatar-small card-user">
      <div class="card-description">
        <a href="<%= posts_path(post.slug) %>"><h3><%= post.title %></h3></a>
        <p><%= post.subtitle %></p>
      </div>
    </div></a>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: As a side note, you might want to think about your controller code. Loading Post.all is not very efficient, imagine you had 1 million or more posts. You would not want to load all of those in like that. Also for your instance variables, you should use just lowercase letter so "@Posts" should be "@posts".

Comment: Thanks for your help @SimonKnight ! Thanks to your answer, all works now ! However, can you explain quickly what is the difference between `@posts` and `@Posts` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code in controller..

1. FIRSTLY,you are fetching posts and then looping it in your view
2. Secondly,you are again fetching users,separately which you should have done along with post,as you want users of each post...

So ideally..you must try something like:-

```
##this will give all post and their respective users
@posts = Post.includes(:users).limit(3)

##in your view

    <%if @posts.present?%>
     <%@posts.each do |post|%>
       <%= post.message%>
       <%= image_tag( post.user.avatar_url)%>
     <%end%>
    <%end%>
```

HOPE IT HELPS :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Milind, actually I just replace `<%= user.image.url(:thumb) %>` by `<%= post.user.image.url(:thumb) %>`and delete  `<% @user.limit(1).each do |user| %>`. In my controller I replace `@Posts = Post.all` by `@Posts = Post.last(3)`. It works now !

Comment: @Florian_CEO..Sounds good.Let me know if my answer was helpful :)